# Movilizer scanning 1D barcode with flash always on

Tags: barcode, movilizer

I need to scan 1D barcode with flashlight always on. Is it possible and if so, how?

code for the screen:

```
<question key="#2" type="22">
    <answer key="#2_1" nextQuestionKey="#4" attributeType="51"/>
    ...
</question>
```

I'm using android 8 device. 
I searched the reference guide for solution, and found nothing useful. 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Scanning on Movilizer clients depends on an external software, so you should need to control it using external events.
For example, if you already have in your Android devide the software for scanning, you need to open a connection to it in the external event, and manange to be closed after finish the scanning time.
In any case, with only this code I'm affraid I cannot help a lot, because there are a lot of scanning ways